Fresh Install - GOTV (Voter Tracking)
On a fresh install of CiviCRM 5.75.1 I am seeing GOTV (Voter Tracking) in the new activity screen:
Survey's additional Info
Is GOTV? ( )Yes (x)No
CiviCampaign / Surveys are not enabled.
How do I get rid of this?


not sure i following, is this a block in a dashboard? perhaps add a screenshot. if you are not using civicampaign you can disable it via Components

Hi, its on the "New Activity" screen, CiviCampaign was enabled then disabled. Could be it is not removed when disabling.

Can you check in your field sets and see if it has left behind some fields you could disable
